# OBTENER PRIMER REGISTRO QUE SE REPITE EN UNA COLUMNA (M:M)

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes!

deseo obtener el primer id de una tabla M:M con select distint.  select distinct no esta funcionando.

Pueden darme una orientacion como realizar la consulta, por favor!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT DISTINCT tarea_actividad.idTarea

,tarea_actividad.idConsignacion

,tarea.ide_cliente

FROM tarea_actividad   

INNER JOIN tarea ON  tarea_actividad.idTarea=tarea.ide_tarea

INNER JOIN cliente ON tarea.ide_cliente=cliente.id

WHERE tarea_actividad.idTarea=333
```

---

Comment: ¿Qué arroja su consulta?

Comment: Si quieres solamente un registro puedes usar `LIMIT 1`. En ese caso usar `DISTINCT` es redundante, no tiene ningún sentido, porque los datos se filtrarán por el `WHERE` combinado con el `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

lo que sucede es que así le coloques el DISTINCT, como en la tabla también está el campo **tarea_actividad.idConsignacion**, el trae el **idTarea = 333** y ademas los 4 registros del campo **tarea_actividad.idConsignacion**. 
Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras. En el primer ejemplo lo que hace es hacer la misma consulta pero solo devuelve 1 registro. En el segundo lo que hace es agrupar todos los datos del campo **idConsignacion** de esta manera

> (4,15,16,17)

```
SELECT DISTINCT tarea_actividad.idTarea

,tarea_actividad.idConsignacion

,tarea.ide_cliente

FROM tarea_actividad   

INNER JOIN tarea ON  tarea_actividad.idTarea=tarea.ide_tarea

INNER JOIN cliente ON tarea.ide_cliente=cliente.id

WHERE tarea_actividad.idTarea=333 LIMIT 1
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT tarea_actividad.idTarea

,GROUP_CONCAT(tarea_actividad.idConsignacion)

,tarea.ide_cliente

FROM tarea_actividad   

INNER JOIN tarea ON  tarea_actividad.idTarea=tarea.ide_tarea

INNER JOIN cliente ON tarea.ide_cliente=cliente.id

WHERE tarea_actividad.idTarea=333
```

Comment: Sr. Raul muchas gracias por su opinion y tomarse el tiempod e responder, interesantes, no lo habia pensado de esa manera.  Lo que habia hecho para realizarlo fue hacerle un  GROUP BY tarea_actividad.idTarea y tambien me habia funcionado. Probe las consultas que ud propone y funcionan muy bien . Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres **una sola fila** usar `DISTINCT` es redundante en este caso.

Mediante el uso de `WHERE tarea_actividad.idTarea=333` combinado con `LIMIT 1`,  obtendrás una sola fila siempre.

De modo que puedes escribir tu consulta así:

```
SELECT 
    tarea_actividad.idTarea,
    tarea_actividad.idConsignacion,
    tarea.ide_cliente
FROM tarea_actividad   
INNER JOIN tarea ON  tarea_actividad.idTarea=tarea.ide_tarea
INNER JOIN cliente ON tarea.ide_cliente=cliente.id
WHERE tarea_actividad.idTarea=333
LIMIT 1;
```

Para más detalles sobre `LIMIT`, puedes [consultar la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html).

Comment: Sr. Cedano, muchas gracias por responder y tomarse el tiempo de aportar buenas ideas. Lo habia solucionado con un group by tarea_actividad.idTarea.  pero con el limit claro perfecto, no lo habia pensado. Muchas gracias.